# C# IF/ELSE statemenets

Tags: c#

I need help with some of my code for a game calculator. So I wrote all this code, but the IF/THEN statement is acting weird.

Screenshot: 
[image]
 -
                 I typed in P and it should have gone to the ELSE part of the code, but instead it continued onto the if part. Please help!

```
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)  // IF YOU ARE TO REWRITE FROM MY SOURCE, ALL ORIGINAL CREDITORS MUST GO INTO THE CREDITS!
        {

            double num01;
            double num02;
            double num03;
            double num04;
            double num05;
            double num06;
            string CD = null;
            string P = null;
            string answer = null;



            Console.Write("Diogenes's Calculator 1.0\n\nCredits: DoS (#57714)\n         DZ(#54689)");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine();


            Console.Write("Hello! Would you like Charity Donation or Propaganda Calculator? (CD or P): ");
            Console.ReadLine();
            answer = Convert.ToString();
            if(answer == CD) {
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.Write("Howmuch influence does the target have?: ");
                num01 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write("Howmuch is the cost of Charity Donatins? (Gold): ");
                num02 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write("What % of  influence does Charity Donation give (Made if value does change)?: ");
                num03 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write(num02 + num03);
                Console.ReadKey();

            } else if(answer == P) {
                answer = Convert.ToString();
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.Write("Howmuch influence does the target have?: ");
                num04 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write("Howmuch influence do you want the target to have?: ");
                num05 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write("What % of  influence does Propaganda take off (Made if value does change)?: ");
                num06 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write(num04 + num05);
                Console.ReadKey();

            } else {
                Console.WriteLine("Looks like you didn't type in CD or P. Buh Bye!");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }



        }
    }
}
```

Comment: P is null and answer is not. You probably meant to write `answer == "P"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are checking if answer is equal to the value stored in the field `P`, not if answer is equal to the actual string "P".  And `P` the variable is null.

Secondly, you are throwing away your user input here:

```
Console.ReadLine();
answer = Convert.ToString();
```

you are reading the console input into nothing, then assigning `answer` to the `Convert` object's string representation, which is probably a fully qualified namespace.  You want:

```
answer = Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: else if(answer == "P") https://gyazo.com/b0ea2b28972fb15871f1698c7d3dbdd0 - no respnse

Comment: you need to work on stepping through your application line by line while you debug it

Comment: It looks like this currently. I don't know how it is broken :(. https://gyazo.com/9b9d7af62483be4d071f606ebba13207

Answer (score 0):

Console.Write("Hello! Would you like Charity Donation or Propaganda Calculator? (CD or P): ");

```
        answer = Console.ReadLine();
        if(answer == "CD") {
```